# How to remove margins between tables with jspdf autotable

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have an Angular application where i use jspdf, but it had a lot of bugs especially when it comes to images and spaces, so i started using jspdf autotable, that seems to be more stable, but the tables have margins betweens the tables. here's my code :

```
    const doc = new jsPDF()
    //@ts-ignore
    doc.autoTable({
        theme: 'plain',
        margin: {top: 0, bottom: 0},
        head: [[ 'Logo mecprog placeholder', {content: 'ORDEM DE SERVIÇO', styles: {fontSize: 20, lineWidth: 1}}, 'logo cliente placeholder']],
        body: [['',{content:  ordemDeServico.cod, styles: {lineWidth: 1}}, '']]
    })
      //@ts-ignore
    doc.autoTable({
        theme: 'plain',
        margin: {top: 0, bottom: 0},
        head: [[ {content:  'Cliente', styles: {lineWidth: 1}},{content:  'Data Progamada', styles: {lineWidth: 1}}, {content:  'Data Executada', styles: {lineWidth: 1}}]],
        body: [[{content:  ordemDeServico.cliente.nomeFantasia, styles: {lineWidth: 1}}, {content:  ordemDeServico.dataProgramada, styles: {lineWidth: 1}},{content: ordemDeServico.dataExecutada, styles: {lineWidth: 1}}]]
    })
    //@ts-ignore
    doc.autoTable({
        theme: 'plain',
        margin: {top: 0, bottom: 0},
        head: [[{content:  'Equipamento', styles: {lineWidth: 1}} , {content:  'Km/Hora Execução', styles: {lineWidth: 1}}, {content:  'Modelo', styles: {lineWidth: 1}}]],
        body: [[{content:  ordemDeServico.equipamento.equipamento, styles: {lineWidth: 1}},{content: this.check(ordemDeServico.quilometroExecucao), styles: {lineWidth: 1}},{content: this.check(ordemDeServico.equipamento.modelo), styles: {lineWidth: 1}}]]
    })
    //@ts-ignore
    doc.autoTable({
      theme: 'plain',
      margin: {top: 0, bottom: 0},
      head: [[{content:  'Equipamento', styles: {lineWidth: 1}} , {content:  'Km/Hora Execução', styles: {lineWidth: 1}}, {content:  'Modelo', styles: {lineWidth: 1}}]],
      body: [[{content:  ordemDeServico.equipamento.equipamento, styles: {lineWidth: 1}},{content: this.check(ordemDeServico.quilometroExecucao), styles: {lineWidth: 1}},{content: this.check(ordemDeServico.equipamento.modelo), styles: {lineWidth: 1}}]]
  })

      doc.save('table.pdf')
```

ordemDeServico is just an object that stores some informations, so it's not important, the thing is that the tables themselves are separated even when i set the margin to 0, so i dont know what should i do

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`doc.lastAutoTable.finalY`](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable#api) with the [`startY`](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable#other-options) parameter like so

```js
doc.autoTable({
   startY: doc.lastAutoTable.finalY + 10, // 10 margin
   //...
})
```